# In fileuploader.js, is it possible to get the parent folder name of uploaded files?

Tags: javascript, file-upload

After looking into fileuploader's getName function (where it indicates it is 'removing the path to normalize'), I found the function is not called.

I have also iterated the variables of a file variable in which the name exists without its path.

Is it possible to retrieve the parent folder name in fileuploader or otherwise (without having to ask the user)?

Comment: https://github.com/Valums-File-Uploader/file-uploader

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.

Browsers replace the path with something along the lines of `c:\fakepath\` to protect the user's privacy.